# QML Camera on Android. Can't set max resolution by viewfinder property

Tags: android, qt, camera

I am testing my qt-opencv-android app on phone: Samsung Galaxy J7. Max resolution of phone video camera is 1920x1080(phone display res: 1280x720). But QML Camera allows to set resolution not more than 1280x720. 
Result of supportedViewfinderResolutions() is the list:
...//...640x480...//...1280x720 (the last! not 1920x1080)
I can set all resolutions in the list by using property "viewfinder.resolution", but not 1920x1080).
Any ideas, how to get videostream from QML Camera with 1920x1080?